# Filter under condition based on value checkbox of current user profile

Tags: views, input-formats

I use Views 3.x and Views PHP module.

**The task.** Make Views filtering criteria that would make two different actions, depending on status of checkbox (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) of current user's profile.

**Description**. Logic diagram:

```
IF checkbox current user == TRUE
THEN display taxonomy terms, tid == New
ELSE display taxonomy terms, tid == array('New', 'Archive', 'Old', ...) // 50+ taxonomy terms
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you display all those 50+ taxonomy terms in a View? If so, you can create a template file for that View and easily convert your logic diagram to code there.

Comment: Example code please, if you can.

Comment: I can, but you have to provide some more information in your question. What are those taxonomy terms? Can you already display them in a View?

Comment: This 50+ terms — it's only example. In real project I have only 3 terms (New, Arhive, Old).

Comment: Question is "Can you already display them in a View"? Answer: yes.

Comment: Maybe there's a Views sub-module that would replace stantard operator "AND" ("OR") in the filtering criteria for this: "IF", "THEN", "ELSE"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can already display the taxonomy terms from the `ELSE` part of your logic diagram in a View, it is quite easy to achieve what you want with a template file for your View. Find the suitable template [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7) and adapt the code underneath, where I assume that you use views-view-field--YOUR_VIEW-YOUR_BOULEAN_FIELD.tpl.php:

```
global $user;
if ($user->field_YOUR_BOULEAN_FIELD['und'][0]['value'] == 1) {
  $output = taxonomy_term_load($tid)->name;
}
```

The variable `$tid` for [`taxonomy_term_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7) should be the tid of your taxonomy term *New*.

Comment: Thx. Is it possible to do it in Views PHP field?

Comment: Yes, I think it would be possible to rewrite the output of the Views field with a PHP snippet, but that isn't possible with Views alone. You'll need the Views PHP module for that. But personally I wouldn't install a new module to rewrite only 1 field.